# How do I fix this SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier?

Tags: javascript

```
on.pitch = event.value+GetParameter('Starting Note'+' 'event.channel)+GetParameter('Number'+' 'event.channel)*12;
```

And the error is:

```
[JS Exception] SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'event'. Expected ')' to end a argument list. line:4
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: give the complete function, but the solution might be passing event as argument.

Comment: You perhaps forgot to add `+`...can you try with this `on.pitch = event.value+GetParameter('Starting Note '+ event.channel)+GetParameter('Number '+event.channel)*12;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the single qoutes before `event`:

```
on.pitch = event.value+GetParameter('Starting Note '+event.channel)+GetParameter('Number '+event.channel)*12;
```